# Wrapping tikz objects with an "eight"

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I want to draw an "eight"(vertical lemniscate) connecting the levels two and three of this simple code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.43, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}

\title{TikZ Level Diagram}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{arr}=[<->,thick];

\node (L3) at (2,1) {$\ket{3}$};
\node (L2) at (2,0) {$\ket{2}$};
\node (L1) at (2,-1) {$\ket{1}$};
\node at (-0.3, 0.6) {$\omega_A$};
\node at (.5,-.4) {$\omega_B$};

\draw[black,thick] (0,1)--(L3);
\draw[black,thick] (0,0)--(L2);
\draw[black,thick] (0,-1)--(L1);
\draw[arr,red] (0,-1)--(0,1);
\draw[arr,blue] (.8,-1)--(.8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Which compiles:

[image]

The "wrapping" that I mention would be something like this one between "hot and cold", but vertically and
between the second and third drawn lines of my code output above(from:https://www.quantamagazine.org/quantum-correlations-reverse-thermodynamic-arrow-of-time-20180402/)

[image]

Comment: Can you make a freehand figure or a photo montage of the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure, that I do not understand how and where the eight should be placed, but here is a start. I just draw a random eight and place it by shifting and scaling it.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{arr}=[<->,thick];
\node (L3) at (2,1) {$\ket{3}$};
\node (L2) at (2,0) {$\ket{2}$};
\node (L1) at (2,-1) {$\ket{1}$};
\node at (-0.3, 0.6) {$\omega_A$};
\node at (.5,-.4) {$\omega_B$};

\draw[black,thick] (0,1)--(L3);
\draw[black,thick] (0,0)--(L2);
\draw[black,thick] (0,-1)--(L1);
\draw[arr,red] (0,-1)--(0,1);
\draw[arr,blue] (.8,-1)--(.8,0);

\begin{scope}[xshift=2, yshift=8, xscale=1, yscale=0.35]
\draw [thick, lime, dashed] (0,0) arc(-225:45:1) -- (0,{sqrt(2)}) arc (225:-45:1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Original image with figure eight]

Comment: Precisely, bravo.